# find and delete duplicates in multiple subdirectorys

Tags: batch-file, find, directory-structure

how can I expand on the following batch code so that everything in the Tim folder is checked against all folders in the Tom directory.

Beter said if Tim has a file named Mytext.txt in it how can I check all and not just the top directory fond starting with C:\Tom, it may be that in tom there is a another folder with an other folder in that yet again with Mytext.txt in it.

All the code below currently dose is check the specifide directory only i would also like to check through any subdirectorys?

```
for /r "C:\Tim" %%f in (*) do if exist "C:\Tom\%%~nxf" del /s /q "C:\Tim\%%~nxf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it, you only need a second `FOR /R` loop, to search in all subdirs of TOM

```
for /r "c:\tim" %%I in (*) do (
  echo searching for %%~nxI
  for /r "C:\tom" %%O in (%%~nxI) do (
    if exist %%O echo found in %%O
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry ive tested it out (rewritten the echo to display a delete instead) but it dosnt seam to work for me.

for /r "c:\tim" %%I in (*) do (
  echo searching for %%~nxI
  for /r "C:\tom" %%O in (%%~nxI) do (
    if exist %%O del /s /q "C:\Tim\%%O"
  )
)

Comment: Please test first, if the echo statement shows you the correct values. As your `del /s /q "C:\tim\%%O` can't work as it would add two times the path, like `del /s /q C:\tim\C:\tim\subdir\myFile.txt`

Comment: @Bart Btw. it's better to edit your post, than to put much code into a comment

Comment: If you only want to delete all files with the name try `del /s /q "%%~nx"`, not ~f else you got the full path again. Btw it's always a good idea to add echo statements where the code fails, like `echo del /s /q "C:\Tim\%%O"`